# VB Folder.CopyHere does not compile with 2nd Statement

Tags: excel, vba, compiler-errors

im currently trying to implement copying a Template Folder to another directory using VB in Excel. I wanted to just show a MsgBox when finishing the copy progress and hide the progress window with VOption (4). As soon as I switch the line away from the .CopyHere command it gives me an compile error.

```
    Dim objFolder As Object
    Dim targetPathNeuanlage1
    targetPathNeuanlage1 = CVar(targetPathNeuanlage)
    
    Set objShell = CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    Set objFolder = objShell.Namespace(targetPathNeuanlage1)
    
    If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        objFolder.CopyHere (ordnervorlage, 4)
        'MsgBox "Kundenordner erfolgreich erstellt!"
    End If
    If (objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        MsgBox "Neuen Ordner nicht gefunden"
    End If
```

Variables "targetPathNeuanlage" and "ordnervorlage" are declared in another sub and are given when the sub is called. The problem is the ", 4" behind "ordnervorlage".
Error is the following: "Compile Error: expected: = "
I don't get why. The method should be fine w the second statement...
Code is working with no issues if code is excecuted without , 4.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Remove the parenthesis. It's not a function. VBA is different than other languages.

Comment: I tried before and i checked once again now. Doesnt work either

Comment: It compiles fine when i removed them. I didn't try to run it tho because your question was about it compiling.

Comment: Microsoft gives the following template to use:
If (Not objFolder Is Nothing) Then
        objFolder.CopyHere ("C:\AUTOEXEC.BAT")
    End If
   And it does compile without parenthesis thats true

Comment: Then why did you put `, 4` in it?

Comment: yep i thought i could work, havent figured another solution yet

Comment: because i wanted to hide the progress window during the copying process

Comment: It seems your question should be "how do i hide the progress window" then?

Comment: Thats a point tho... im sorry, new to this and have to learn how to ask very precisely

Comment: See - https://serverfault.com/questions/306559/why-does-the-net-folder-copyhere-method-not-allow-dialog-suppression-for-zip-f   Seems like you cannot suppress the dialog when copying to a compressed folder.

Comment: i ain't copying to a compressed folder, just a normal file driectory. Btw when excecuting the code without parenthesis it doesnt even copy the folder

Comment: OK sorry missed that.  `ordnervorlage` is a variant?

Comment: If you are just copying a file, what's wrong with `CopyFile`? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/copyfile-method

Comment: Yes i tried before, but unfortunately some of the directorypaths are too long too handle for vba, so i had to use a shell cmd, ordnervorlage wasnt a variant - it is now. code is working, except for the , 4 . I tried with hex as well &H4& but the small progress window opens every time

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

No progress bar:

```vb
With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    .Namespace("C:\Temp\F2").CopyHere .Namespace("C:\Temp\F1").Items, 4
End With
```

With progress bar:

```vb
With CreateObject("Shell.Application")
    .Namespace("C:\Temp\F2").CopyHere .Namespace("C:\Temp\F1").Items
End With
```

Comment: it gives me "Runtime error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set" do have to declare any variables?

Comment: I figured out that the `.Items` was the part that causes the error. Anyways if i remove it it does not copy the folder. i'm despairing more and more haha

Comment: It might help to update your post and add the current version of your code - if possible include all relevant parts (enough for someone to test it themselves)

Comment: Works for me too (office 365 x64).